# How to open messages in edit mode?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When handling and filing fax-messages (that include .tif files), I sometimes need to rotate the images which were sent "upside down"; in order to do that I open the message.
I then click the "edit" button/action. Now, I open the .tif file - and if needed I rotate the file then close and save the message with the rotated file.

I would like my messages, by default, to open editable so I can skip one step in the process. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Thank you for the English lesson. Can you also help with the subject matter itself?